# What old science fiction story is Lafferty alluding to in Okla Hannali?

Tags: story-identification

From Chapter 18 of [R. A. Lafferty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/R._A._Lafferty)'s historical novel [*Okla Hannali*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?110664) (emphasis added):

> There is an interesting question in the *Summa* of St. Thomas Aquinas and also in **an old science fiction story, the name of which I forget,** concerning the paradox of free will and predestined fate. It asks whether a man in making a great decision that will forever set the seal on his future does not also set the seal on his past. A man alters his future, and does he not also alter his past in conformity with it? Does he not settle not only what manner of man he will be, but also what manner of man he has been?

What "old science fiction story" is Lafferty alluding to here?

*Okla Hannali* was published in 1972. It can be borrowed from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/search?query=okla+hannali).

Comment: "The Garden of Forking Paths," while it doesn't frame the issue as *fixing* either future or past, does make a point of emphasizing that for an observer in the present, the past and future are equally uncertain and undetermined.

Answer (score 9):

Lafferty might be referring to his own short story [Thus We Frustrate Charlemagne](https://ttdlabyrinth.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/reprint-thus-we-frustrate-charlemagne/), first published in [Galaxy, 1967](https://isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?52255).  It's a short tale involving multiple attempts to change history.  Shenanigans ensue.

I cannot find a copy on line.  The first link has a lengthy discussion of the story.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/Galaxy_v25n03_1967-02/page/n125/mode/2up

Comment: I'm familiar with that story. Why do you think it's the one Lafferty is talking about?

Comment: I don't see a similarity.  Not knowing Lafferty's sense of humor if he's being serious or coy and self referential - I too would suspect this is a way to promote an author's own story - just not this one. Honestly pre-1970 SF story about predestination is way too vague to answer with any certainty in my opinion.

Comment: @lucasbachmann Seems pretty vague to me too, but maybe there is a "word of God" about this in some other Lafferty writing or interview.